# how to rotate a symbol

Tags: qgis, python, symbology, c++, api

I am working in c++/python/QT 4.5 with the api qgis 2.8.2

My application receive data from a communication port that indicate the change of position of an object diplayed on the map and represented by a svg ( an arrow )
the data received contains new position x and y and the rotation in degree

I want to rotate the symbol with the value received, if value equal 0 there is no rotation, if the value is 30 then rotate the symbol of 30 deg clockwise

I don't know how to do that, may be some of you had already work on that kind of point and share their procedure

Answer (score 1):

In qgis api 2.8.2, i found a simple way to do that but it correspond to my application perhaps this inspire you to find another way

in fact for each point or track i create a vectorlayer and i change the value of the vectorlayer angle

```
QStringList MyTargetPropertyName;
MyTargetPropertyName << "fill" << "name" << "outline" << "outline-width" << "size" << "angle";
QStringList MyTargetPropertyValue1;
MyTargetPropertyValue1 << "#f3e54d" << lTargetIcoType1 << "#000000" << "6.8" << "6" << lAngle;

for (int i = 0; i < MyTargetPropertyName.size(); i++)
    MyTargetStyle1.insert(MyTargetPropertyName.at(i),MyTargetPropertyValue1.at(i));
MySymbolLayer1 = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2::create(MyTargetStyle1);
QList<QgsSymbolLayerV2*> MyLayerList;
MyLayerList << MySymbolLayer1;
QgsSymbolV2* newsymbol = QgsSymbolV2::defaultSymbol(
            pLayer->geometryType());
newsymbol->deleteSymbolLayer(0);
newsymbol->insertSymbolLayer(0, MyLayerList[0]);
```

this is just an extract but the essential of the code is here.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for a code snippet which does the question above described, as I need to rotate each symbol the value provided azimuth field at the attribute table.

At the QGIS python Cookbook there is a [reference](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#working-with-symbols), which mentions the way to print the angle().

```
for i in xrange(symbol.symbolLayerCount()):
    lyr = symbol.symbolLayer(i)
    print "%d: %s" % (i, lyr.layerType())
```

This could be done to obtain the angle: lyr.angle(), but this does not rotate the symbol.

In that same chapter, you can find this section [Creating Custom Symbol Layer Types](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#creating-custom-symbol-layer-types) which describes a process that Im sure could be used for this purpose. When I execute `QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().addSymbolLayerType(FooSymbolLayerMetadata())`, however I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/Users/EGARFEL/Desktop/Optimi Documents/atmMobilis/qgisScript.py", line 76, in 
    QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().addSymbolLayerType(FooSymbolLayerMetadata())

```
 File "C:/Users/EGARFEL/Desktop/Optimi Documents/atmMobilis/qgisScript.py", line 58, in __init__
    QgsSymbolLayerV2AbstractMetadata.__init__(self, "FooMarker", QgsSymbolV2.Marker)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsSymbolLayerV2AbstractMetadata(QString, QString, QgsSymbolV2.SymbolType): argument 2 has unexpected type 'SymbolType'
  QgsSymbolLayerV2AbstractMetadata(QgsSymbolLayerV2AbstractMetadata): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```